# Can't import functions into Vue.js Single File Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have several vue's which require custom date functions. I am attempting to create a date_module.

datemodule.js

```
export default {
    getNewDate(offset){
        let newDate = this.getDate();
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + offset);
        return newDate;
    },
    getDate(){
        let date = new Date();
        return date;
    },
    ...etc
}
```

I am attempting to import it and call it in my components as DM.getDate() etc.

DailySchedule.vue

```
...
import DM from "../datemodule.js"
...
```

This doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Are you using vue-cli? The import is inside the `script` tags? What is the file structure?

Comment: The import is inside the script tags in a single file component. Component is in /views and the datemodule.js is one dir above... same level as main.js or index.js

Answer (score 2):

Try refactor `datemodule.js`:

```
function getNewDate(offset){
  let newDate = this.getDate();
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + offset)        
  return newDate;
}

function getDate(){
  let date = new Date();
  return date
}

export default { getNewDate, getDate }
```

And then `import DM from '../datemodule.js'`. Notice you are writing normal javascript modules here instead of a Vue component.

Comment: I have tried this method but same result... DM undefined.

Comment: If I call the functions in the data function I get this error...
data(): "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__datemodule_js__.a.getDayOfWeek is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

here i had a sample and this worked for me.

dateUtils.js

```
import moment from "moment";

export const convertDate = (date) => {
  return moment(date).format("DD MMMM YYYY");
};
```

Then to use Convertdate function like :

```
import {convertDate} from "./dateUtils.js";


setup(){
   convertDate("date")
}
```